# React - Class signature on mouse over

Tags: reactjs, class

First, sorry for my english: i'm french
I appreciate the signature (props details required for a function component) like this:
[A Bootstrap component signature with VSC IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50Uhn.png).
And i also use this possibility with my own functions.
I don't know how to do for having the same result with a class component.
Is it technically possible with React?
Can someone will give me an example in this case, please
In advance, thanks a lot

I try to "explode" props in order to do that but it doesn't work.
[an Example of a Class Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOd2Y.png)

Comment: Based on the example you showed, it is possible. However I couldn.t see a body of the component. Could you share the code please?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.